# Basic Python HTTP Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, server

It's an extremely simply HTTP server in Python using the socket library, and a few others to get the MIME type, etc...

I've also avoided the `../../` vulnerability, although some of the code in the `send_file` function seems a bit weak.

It should also be PEP8 compliant, aside from maybe some trailing whitespace in comments.

```py
import filetype
import socket
import _thread


class ServerSocket():
    ''' Recieves connections, parses the request and ships it off to a handler
    '''
    def __init__(self, address, handler=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Creates a server socket and defines a handler for the server
        '''
        self.socket = socket.socket()
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(address)

        self.handler_args = args
        self.handler_kwargs = kwargs

        if handler:
            self.handler = handler  # The custom handler
        else:
            self.handler = Handler  # The default handler

    def initialise(self, open_connections=5):
        ''' Initilises the server socket and has it listen for connections
        '''
        self.socket.listen(open_connections)
        self.listen()

    def parse(self, data):
        ''' Splits a packet into
                the request,
                the headers (which includes the request),
                and contents
        '''
        stringed = str(data, 'utf-8')
        split = stringed.split('\r\n\r\n')
        headers = split[0]
        if len(split) > 1:
            content = split[1]
        else:
            content = []
        request = headers.split(' ')[0]

        return request, headers, content

    def handle(self, client, address):
        ''' Parses the data and handles the request. It then closes the connection
        '''
        try:
            data = client.recv(1024)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            if self.handler_kwargs["logging"] is True:
                print(f'{address[0]} unexpectedly quit')
            client.close()
            return
        parsed = self.parse(data)
        handler = self.handler(self.handler_args, self.handler_kwargs)
        handler.handle(client, parsed, address)
        client.close()

    def listen(self):
        ''' Listens until a keyboard interrupt and handles each connection in a
                new thread
        '''
        try:
            while True:
                client_data = self.socket.accept()
                if self.handler_kwargs['logging'] is True:
                    print(f'Connection from {client_data[1][0]}')
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.handle, client_data)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.socket.close()


class Handler():
    ''' Handles requests from the Server Socket
    '''
    def __init__(self, args, kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def set_status(self, code, message):
        ''' Used to add a status line:
                - 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' or 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', etc...
        '''
        self.reply_headers = [f'HTTP/1.0 {code} {message}']

    def set_header(self, header, content):
        ''' Defines a custom header and adds it to the response
        '''
        self.reply_headers += [f'{header}: {content}']

    def response(self, content):
        ''' Adds to the content of the response
        '''
        if type(content) == str:
            self.reply_content += content.split('\n')
        else:
            self.reply_content += [content]

    def calculate_content_length(self):
        ''' Calculates the content length and adds it to the header
        '''
        length = len(self.reply_content) * 2
        lengths = [len(line) for line in self.reply_content]
        length += sum(lengths)
        self.set_header('Content-Length', length)

    def get_type(self, file_name):
        return filetype.guess('./public/'+file_name)

    def extract_file_name(self, file_name=None):
        if file_name:
            f_name = file_name[1:]
        else:
            f_name = self.request_status.split(' ')[1][1:]
        return f_name

    def send_file(self, file_name=None):
        if file_name is None:
            file_name = self.extract_file_name()

        if file_name == '':
            file_name = 'index.html'
        elif file_name[0] in './':
            self.set_status(403, "Forbidden")
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.reply_content = ['<p>Error 403: Forbidden</p>']
            return

        try:
            with open('./public/'+file_name, 'rb') as file:
                file_contents = file.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.set_status(404, 'Not Found')
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.reply_content = ['<p>Error 404: File not found</p>']
            return
        file_type = self.get_type(file_name)
        if file_type is not None:
            self.set_header('Content-Type', file_type.MIME)
        elif file_name.split('.')[-1] == 'html':
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        else:
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/txt')
        self.response(file_contents)

    def get_request_address(self):
        return self.address

    def parse_headers(self, headers):
        t = {}
        for header in headers[1:]:
            t[header.split(': ')[0]] = header.split(': ')[1]
        return t

    def reply(self):
        ''' Assembles the response and sends it to the client
        '''
        if self.reply_headers[0][0:4] != "HTTP":
            self.set_status(200, 'OK')
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.reply_content = ['<p>Response Status unspecified</p>']

        self.calculate_content_length()

        message = '\r\n'.join(self.reply_headers)
        message += '\r\n\r\n'
        try:
            message += '\r\n'.join(self.reply_content)
            message += '\r\n'
        except TypeError:
            message = bytes(message, 'utf-8')
            message += b'\r\n'.join(self.reply_content)
            message += b'\r\n'

        try:
            if type(message) == str:
                self.client.send(bytes(message, 'utf-8'))
            else:
                self.client.send(message)
        except:
            pass

    def handle(self, client, parsed_data, address):
        ''' Initialises variables and case-switches the request type to
                determine the handler function
        '''
        self.client = client
        self.address = address
        self.reply_headers = []
        self.reply_content = []
        self.headers = True
        self.request_status = parsed_data[1].split('\r\n')[0]
        request = parsed_data[0]
        headers = self.parse_headers(parsed_data[1].split('\r\n'))
        contents = parsed_data[2]

        if request == "GET":
            func = self.get
        elif request == "POST":
            func = self.post
        elif request == "HEAD":
            func = self.head
        elif request == "PUT":
            func = self.put
        elif request == "DELETE":
            func = self.delete
        elif request == "CONNECT":
            func = self.connect
        elif request == "OPTIONS":
            func = self.options
        elif request == "TRACE":
            func = self.trace
        elif request == "PATCH":
            func = self.patch
        else:
            func = self.default

        func(headers, contents)
        self.reply()

    def default(self, headers, contents):
        ''' If the request is not known, defaults to this
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Unknown Request Type</p>''')

    def get(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle GET requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a GET Request</p>''')

    def post(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle POST requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a POST Request</p>''')

    def head(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle HEAD requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a HEAD Request</p>''')

    def put(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle PUT requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a PUT Request</p>''')

    def delete(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle DELETE requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a DELETE Request</p>''')

    def connect(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle CONNECT requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a CONNECT Request</p>''')

    def options(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle OPTIONS requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got an OPTIONS Request</p>''')

    def trace(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle TRACE requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a TRACE Request</p>''')

    def patch(self, headers, contents):
        ''' Overwrite to customly handle PATCH requests
        '''
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.response('''<p>Successfully got a PATCH Request</p>''')


# =======================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    class CustomHandler(Handler):
        def get(self, headers, contents):
            self.set_status(200, 'OK')
            request_address = self.get_request_address()[0]
            file_name = self.extract_file_name()
            print(f'{request_address} -> {headers["Host"]}/{file_name}')
            self.send_file()

    def run():
        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
            port = int(sys.argv[1])
        else:
            port = 80

        try:
            print('Initialising...', end='')
            http_server = ServerSocket(
                ('0.0.0.0', port),
                CustomHandler,
                logging=True
            )
            print('Done')
            http_server.initialise()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'{e}')

    run()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## ServerSocket

### self.handler

The handler evaluation in `__init__` can be accomplished with an `or` ternary operation. It's clearer to the reader as to what's going on. Also, the name could be changed to `HandlerClass`, since it represents a `class` rather than an instance:

```py
    self.HandlerClass = handler or Handler
```

### `self.handler` logging

The check against `handler_kwargs` makes the code a bit difficult to follow, since the `SocketServer` is now in charge of something that arguably the `handler` should be doing. If the *server* is who should be doing the logging, then I would leave the logging check out of the `handler_kwargs` entirely. Store `self.logging` as a boolean setting on the server instance, and just check against that:

```py
# for traceback handling
import traceback 

class SocketServer:
    def __init__(self, address, handler=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ~skipping some code~

        # this is so you don't unpack logging from kwargs since
        # it looks like you need it in your handler
        self.logging = kwargs.get('logging', False)

        ...

    def handle(self):
        try:
            data = client.recv(1024)
        except ConnectionResetError as e:
            # use the more pythonic `if bool` check
            # here, rather than comparing against a singleton
            if self.logging:
                print(f'{address[0]} unexpectedly quit: {e}', file=sys.stderr)
                traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), file=sys.stderr)
```

I've added a `sys.stderr` stream to your print statement, and added the exception to your print statement. I've also added a traceback print which points to stderr.

### `handle` Refactor

The `client.close(); return` statement can also be refactored using `try/except`'s `else` feature and a `finally` block, since you *always* want the client to close

```py
        try:
            data = client.recv(1024)
        except ConnectionResetError as e:
            if self.logging:
                print(f'{address[0]} unexpectedly quit: {e}', file=sys.stderr)
                traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), file=sys.stderr) 
        # this is if no exception fired
        else:
            parsed = self.parse(data)
            handler = self.HandlerClass()
            handler.handle(client, parsed, address)
        # this will always execute
        finally:
            client.close()
```

### Convert `bytes` to `str`

### `parse`

First, when converting bytes to str, use `bytes.decode()` rather than `str(byte_obj, encoding)`. The `headers` and `content` evaluation can be handled using argument unpacking, and from there you can use an `or` expression with `any` on `contents` to either take the first result or create an empty list:

```py
    def parse(self, data):
        ''' Splits a packet into
                the request,
                the headers (which includes the request),
                and contents
        '''
        stringed = data.decode().split('\r\n\r\n')

        # The headers and content blocks can be handled also with argument
        # unpacking and a ternary operator on content:

        headers, *content = data.decode().split('\r\n\r\n')
        content = content[0] if content else []

        request = headers.split(' ')[0]

        return request, headers, content
```

## Handler

### Adding to lists

There are lots of cases where you do this:

```py
self.some_list += [some_value]
```

Just use `.append(some_value)`, it's faster since you don't have to create a list just to add the value to an existing list. For example:

```py
    def set_header(self, header, content):
        ''' Defines a custom header and adds it to the response
        '''
        # this is much quicker, do this instead
        self.reply_headers.append(f'{header}: {content}')
```

### type-checking

Use `isinstance` rather than `type(object) == some_type`:

```py
# This
    def response(self, content):
        ''' Adds to the content of the response
        '''
        if type(content) == str:
            self.reply_content += content.split('\n')
        else:
            self.reply_content += [content]

# should be this
    def response(self, content):
        if isinstance(content, str):
            self.reply_content.extend(content.split('\n'))
        else:
            self.reply_content.append(content)
```

Note that I'm also switching the addition of lists to appropriate calls to `append` and `extend`. Though, looking through the rest of your code, you only use this against `str` or `bytes` types, so I'd refactor to the following:

```py
    def response(self, content):
        # force everything to bytes-type for convenience, that way
        # you never have to worry about TypeErrors later
        content = content if isinstance(content, bytes) else content.encode()

        self.reply_content.append(content)
```

### content-length calculation

Here, you can drop the creation of the `lengths` list, and just use `sum` on `map`:

```py
    def calculate_content_length(self):
        ''' Calculates the content length and adds it to the header
        '''
        length = len(self.reply_content) * 2

        # sum will take any iterable, even generators and maps
        # len in map is the function to be applied to each element
        length += sum(map(len, self.reply_content))
        self.set_header('Content-Length', length)
```

It's faster and doesn't build as many objects inside the function

## Magic Numbers

In your `extract_file_name` function, you are slicing the file name from the first element, though it's not completely clear why:

```py
    def extract_file_name(self, file_name=None):
        if file_name:
            f_name = file_name[1:]
        else:
            f_name = self.request_status.split(' ')[1][1:]
        return f_name
```

This is usually a code smell and you should include a docstring and/or comments to explain why you slice that way. Otherwise, the index is a "magic number" and can be difficult for you or others to maintain later. You also never use the `file_name` argument at any point when calling this function, so I might just leave it out.

### Sending Files

Most of the improvements here follow the ones that have been suggested above:

#### Ternary Operation or Use `or` for `file_name`

```py
file_name = file_name or self.extract_file_name()

## or 

file_name = file_name if file_name else self.extract_file_name()
```

The latter mirrors your `if` statement a bit more

#### Checking an empty string

Use `if some_string` not `if some_string == ''`.

#### Checking string start and end values

The `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` methods will help here, and they avoid indexing or slicing which can impair readability:

```py
if file_name.startswith('./'):
    # do something


if file_name.endswith('html'):
    # do something
```

The logic in `send_file` could be cleaned up a bit. First, I think a `handle_error` method would do nicely to clean up some of the repeated code where you handle exceptions:

```py
    def handle_error(self, code, short_reason, reason):
        """
        code: integer error code
        short_reason: string denoting the short error reason
        reason: string denoting the full error reason

        example:
            self.handle_error(404, 'Not Found', 'File Not Found')
        """
        self.set_status(code, short_reason)
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.reply_content = [f'<p>Error {code}: {reason} </p>']
```

Next, I think the filename checking can be refactored to make a bit more sense. First, it seems a bit counterintuitive that a path that might start with `'.'` is forbidden. What about `./public/index.html`? If you're trying to avoid folder traversal such as paths with `.` and `..` in them, it might not be that bad to use a regex. For example, what if I tried to give you a path like `../../root_file.txt'? It would pass your test, even though it will traverse back directories. I would do something like the following:

```py
import re
~skipping lots of code~

    @staticmethod
    def valid_path(path):
        """
        Will take any unix-path and check for any '.' and '..' directories
        in it. Example:

            import re
            re_path = re.compile('^\.+$')

            some_path = '/root/path/to/../folder/./file.txt'
            public_path = 'public/folder/../../../file.txt'

            next(filter(re_path.match, some_path.split('/')))
            # '..'

            '/'.join(filter(re_path.match, some_path.split('/')))
            # '..'
            valid_path = '/path/to/file.txt'
            next(filter(re_path.match, valid_path.split('/')))
            StopIteration
        """
        path = path.lstrip('.').lstrip('/')
        re_path = re.compile('^\.+$')
        try:
            match = next(filter(re_path.match, path.split('/')))
        except StopIteration:
            return True
        return False
```

This way you can check if there are backout paths without colliding with something inocuous like `./public/file.txt`, and you can handle the following `FileNotFoundError`. Otherwise, you'll get a `None` on return, and then you can return an `AccessDenied`:

```py
    def send_file(self, file_name=None):
        ~snip~
        # this is more pythonic than doing
        # if file_name == ''
        file_name = file_name or 'index.html'

        # will either be True or False
        if not self.valid_path(file_name):
            # I've added the keywords here for clarity
            self.handle_error(403, short_reason='Forbidden', reason='Forbidden')
            return  

        try:
            # use and f-string here rather than string
            # concatenation
            with open(f'./public/{file_name}', 'rb') as fh:
                file_contents = file.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.handle_error(404, short_reason='Not Found', reason='File Not Found')
            return

        file_type = self.get_type(file_name)
        if file_type is not None:
            self.set_header('Content-Type', file_type.MIME)
        # use str.endswith here
        elif file_name.endswith('html'):
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        else:
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/txt')

        self.response(file_contents)
```

### Redundant Methods

The method `get_request_address` in my opinion doesn't need to be there. Just access `self.address` wherever you call it.

### `parse_headers`

If it were up to me, I'd make the headers a dictionary from the get-go, but this can be re-factored like so:

```py
    # this can be static since you never access any self attributes
    @staticmethod
    def parse_headers(headers):
        t = {}
        for header in headers[1:]:
            # unpack k and v from one call to split
            k, v = header.split(': ')
            t[k] = v
        return t
```

Or, even more succinctly

```py
    @staticmethod
    def parse_headers(headers):
        return dict(header.split(': ') for header in headers[1:])
```

### `reply`

Again, I'd force everything to `bytes`. You try to append to a `str` (`message`) with mixed types, which will fail:

```py
    def reply(self):
        ''' Assembles the response and sends it to the client
        '''
        if not self.reply_headers[0].startswith("HTTP"):
            self.set_status(200, 'OK')
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.reply_content = ['<p>Response Status unspecified</p>']

        self.calculate_content_length()

        # here's how to coerce to bytes on reply_headers
        message = b'\r\n'.join(map(str.encode, self.reply_headers))
        message += b'\r\n\r\n'


        message += b'\r\n'.join(x.encode() if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in self.reply_content))
        message += b'\r\n'

        # Now you don't have to type-check
        try:
            self.client.send(message)
        except:
            pass
```

Avoiding the type-checking entirely makes your code more streamlined and maintainable.

Last, instead of using `pass` on an unexpected Exception, I'd raise some sort of `500`:

```py
     try:
         self.client.send(message)
     except Exception as e:
         traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info(), file=sys.stderr)
         self.handle_error(500, 'Server Error', 'Internal Server Error')
```

Then at the very least there's some visibility either by the client or by you that something bad happened.

### `handle`

This is a classic case of don't repeat yourself. Looking at the big block of `if` statements, your execution times will be slightly worse for a `PATCH` than a `GET`. To refactor, I would use a dictionary that binds the names of functions to operations, yielding a constant time lookup:

```
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ~snip~
        self.functions = {
            'GET': self.get,
            'POST': self.post,
            'HEAD': self.head,
            'PUT': self.put,
            'DELETE': self.delete,
            'CONNECT': self.connect,
            'OPTIONS': self.options,
            'TRACE': self.trace,
            'PATCH': self.patch
        }


    def call_method(self, contents, request_type=None, headers=None):
        headers = headers or {}

        headers['Content-Type'] = headers.get('Content-Type', 'text/html')

        self.set_status(200, 'OK')

        for k, v in headers.items():
            self.set_header(k, v)

        func = self.functions.get(request_type.upper() if request_type else '', self.default)

        func(headers, contents)
        self.reply()
```